# What is the phrase or idiom for this "Member of neither group"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

**Description #1**

A person from a democratic country hates democracy and loves communism. So, he moves to a communist country.

People from the communist country don't like him as he is a citizen of a democratic country and a foreigner.

So, he moves back to his previous country. Now, people there also hate him because he hates democracy.

Now, he is an orphan or pariah.

**Description #2**

A person changes his religion from 'X' to 'Y.' However, he is not regarded as a member of the community of 'Y' because he was not born with that religion. Now, the community of 'X' also disowns him because of his conversion.

Now, he is an orphan or pariah.

---

What phrase or idiom can I use to describe the person?

Comment: Like a logical NOR? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR

Comment: "Neither side likes him" or "Both sides disapprove of him"?

Comment: He is a[*Man Without A Country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Without_a_Country). If you look at the disambiguation page, you will find 4 movies, an opera, and a poetry collection that was made into an album by Bing Crosby. It is a very well-known story.

Comment: @Phil Sweet Klingons and Vulcans?

Comment: Much better question now.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "pariah". Do you have reason to believe that there's a multi-word phrase or idiom that works better?

Answer (score 1):

[Outcast](https://www.wordwebonline.com/en/OUTCAST)
A person who is rejected (from society or home)

[Ostracize](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of-the-word/ostracized.html)
Expel or Exclude (a Person) from society or from a community

[Persona non grata](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persona%20non%20grata)
Person who is unacceptable or unwelcome

Here I would suggest **"universal outcast"** or **"universally ostracized"** or **"Universal Persona non grata"** to suit your Situation.

Comment: ***why*** would you suggest these? And where are your links from? That has to be given in plain text, not hidden behind a link. Please review our [Helper Center's guidance on how to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score -1):

**Fence sitter** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fence_sitter#English))

> One who takes neither side of an argument or controversy, but
> maintains a neutral position.

**Nonpartisan** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonpartisan))

> One who is not a partisan.
> A person who has not selected or declared a side or party.

**Sui generis** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sui_generis))

> In a class of its own; one of a kind.
>
> (rarer) By itself; of its own.

Comment: Pariah, outcast, persona non grata had already been mentioned. What do you want from the word? You can mention that in your question. That would help other members to come up with better alternatives. Other negative words that may be usable are Persona non undesirable, unwelcome, marooned person or socially rejected.

Comment: This is not an answer. It is copypasta. Please explain why you think any of these answer the question ***in your own words***.